# Add values conditionally without IF-ELSE in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, string

I am looking for adding some values in a variable without using multiple if-else

I have a variable var inclusion = ''; //initialized to empty

I have 3 other variables: p1val, p2val, p3val // all 3 are arrays

I am looking for below output in my case:

1. If p1val is not empty but p2val and p3val are empty then inclusion = 'Includes P1' //P1 here is hardcoded text. That will always be hardcoded
2. If p2val is not empty but p1val and p3val are empty then inclusion = 'Includes P2' //P2 here is hardcoded text. That will always be hardcoded
3. If p3val is not empty but p1val and p2val are empty then inclusion = 'Includes P3' //P3 here is hardcoded text. That will always be hardcoded
4. If p1val,p2val is not empty but p3val is empty then inclusion = 'Includes P1 and P2'
5. If p1val,p3val is not empty but p2val is empty then inclusion = 'Includes P1 and P3'
6. If p2val,p3val is not empty but p1val is empty then inclusion = 'Includes P2 and P3'
7. If p1val,p2val,p3val is not empty then inclusion = 'Includes P1, P2 and P3'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: So you only want to include the names of arrays that have values? What if all of them are empty?

Comment: Yes. If all are empty inclusion will be ''

Answer (score 3):

Why no ifs?

This is sort of without if

If `P1, P2` without the `and` is ok, then you can delete  `.replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, ' and')`

```js
let p1Val = ["1"],
 p2Val = [],
 p3Val = ["3"]
 inclusionArr = [];
 
 p1Val.length && inclusionArr.push("P1")
 p2Val.length && inclusionArr.push("P2")
 p3Val.length && inclusionArr.push("P3")

const inclusion = inclusionArr.length ? `Includes ${inclusionArr.join(", ").replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, ' and')}`: '';
console.log(inclusion)
```